# I get this annoying error in my php code! How can I solve it?

Tags: php

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\example\example2.php on line 23

My code looks like this:
        
    
        
            Exemplu
        
        
            
            Email
            Password

```
    <?php
        $con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","amit");
        if(isset($_POST['login'])){
            $email= mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
            $password= mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass']);
            $select_user= "SELECT > FROM example WHERE Email='$email' AND Passwords='$password'";
            $run_user= mysqli_master_query($con , $select_user);
            $check_user= mysqli_num_rows($run_user);
            if($check_user > 0) {
                header('location:home.php')
            }else{echo "wrong username or password";
        }






        }
    ?>
```

What is the problem with it on line 23? (Line 23 is where the second if begins)

Comment: **WARNING** `mysqli_master_query` has been _DEPRECATED_ and _REMOVED_ as of PHP 5.3.0.

Comment: Look at the last bracket **{** it shoudn't be  there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing `;` in `header('location:home.php')`

It should be:

```
if($check_user > 0) {
    header('location:home.php');
    }else{
        echo "wrong username or password";
      }
```

**Upadated:**

Another Problem with `SELECT >` it should be `SELECT *`
**Your Code:**

```
$select_user= "SELECT > FROM example WHERE Email='$email' AND Passwords='$password'";
```

**It should be:**

```
$select_user= "SELECT * FROM example WHERE Email='$email' AND Passwords='$password'";
```

**Comments Problem:**

You have used `mysqli_master_query()` but This function is currently not documented; only its argument list is available. Please see the website **[doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-master-query.php).**

Comment: That was it! I can't believe I didn't put that there!I really appreciate your help! Thank you!

Comment: Please accept this an answer if it solved your issue. It helps future SO users.

Comment: What about this one? It's saying about my num rows function. It's just a warning but it's there. 

        Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\example\example2.php on line 20

Comment: @Alok 12 minutes must have passed since I posted the question in order to accept any answer. I will as soon as I can.

Comment: @VladutMaican Awesome!

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud How can I solve this good sir?
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\example\example2.php on line 20

Answer (score 0):

instead

```
header('location:home.php')
```

use

```
header('location:home.php');
```

Comment: Where is the difference ?!

Comment: semi column (;) at the end of the line

Comment: Ahh ! you better add this to your answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Just use a semicolon after your header location line.

Also, I don't see a reason for this SELECT >

Try writing cleaner code.

```
 <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","amit") or die(mysqli_connect_error());

    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

        $email    = mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
        $password = mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass']);

        $select_user = "SELECT * FROM example WHERE Email= '".$email."' AND Passwords='".$password."'";
        $run_user    = mysqli_query($con , $select_user) or mysqli_error($con); // 
        $check_user  = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);

       if ($check_user > 0) {
            header('location:home.php');
        } else {
           echo "wrong username or password";
        }
     }
  ?>
```

On a side note, using functions like mysqli_error and mysqli_connect_error really helps in debugging.
You may wanna refer to these:

[Simple mysqli set up](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-examples)

[mysqli error functions](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php#refsect1-mysqli.error-examples)

Comment: Thank you!
What is this error tho'?
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\example\example2.php on line 20

Comment: That's because your previous line has some SQL syntax error. I'm a bit skeptical about mysqli_master_query. Is there a reason why you can't use mysqli_query()??